# How to set Android app badge count when app is foreground in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, badge, foreground

When app is background(inactivated or closed),
if firebase notification is arrived, app badge is showed.
But when app is foreground(activated),
if firebase notification is arrived, app badge is not showed.
It seems like below.

> - If app is foreground, android does not display badge.
> - Once badge is showed, You can set badge count. It is not concerned with app status(foreground or background).
> - Once badge is showed, You can set badge count without notification. Anywhere and any events.

I tried like below.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    // Used flutter_app_badger. It works only when app badge is already showed.
    FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);

    // Tried use native code invocation. It works only when app badge is already showed.
    const platform = const MethodChannel('channel_name');
    final dynamic result = await platform.invokeMethod('setBadge', {
        'count': 1
    });
});
```

This is invoked kotlin code from flutter.

```
var count =  call.argument<Int>("count") as Int
val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE")
    .putExtra("badge_count", count)
    .putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.packageName)
    .putExtra("badge_count_class_name", getLauncherMainClassName())
context.sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
[flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) can solve this problom.

Comment: Please provide a sample code to explain how you achieve this instead of sharing a link.

Comment: Quote from the readme: "This plugin doesn't provide APIs for directly setting the badge count for your application. If you need this for your application, there are other plugins available, such as the flutter_app_badger plugin."